# Personal Network Security -How can I stop getting my Laptop knocked off my Wifi?

Tags: wifi, router

In my neighborhood there are 26 wifi gateways and I keep switching channels. If you split all the gateways on 10 g freq channels plus the n frequency channels that still is enough for all of them.

However, I keep on getting my wifi knocked off and it is starting to feel intentional.

How can I discover what is the cause that knocks of my connection from the router?

netgear r7000
mac osx 10.8.5

Comment: .... read the logs?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number a possible causes.

Check if your wireless device is configured to drop connections when the signal strength drops below some minimum threshold, I've known a number of devices to have this "feature". That's only a potential issue if you have a weak signal though. Also check that your SSID is unique so that it isn't clashing with another access point.

I would try changing the WPA/WEP key and your router login credentials to rule out the possibility of someone else kicking you off your own network e.g. by logging into your router and messing around.

Another option is to check if you have WPS enabled. If this is active then one of your neighbours could be trying to brute force their way into your network which could be affecting your network's stability. Not all routers ship with this feature or even if they do, many of them don't allow you to disable it.

If nothing else works I suppose you could take your router somewhere else far from where it is presently located and see if you still have issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your last suggestion is good in that it tests whether the AP or client wireless hardware is faulty.  I have seen some consumer wireless gear mess up because of a cheap power adapter or poorly wired power outlet / infrastructure.  That kind of problem would elude that test, so another test could be devised if OP's troubleshooting got that far, such as swapping for a similar known-good power adapter, changing outlets, etc.

Comment: agh I think its all the interference and possible FBI snooping as to sometimes I see an FBI Van in my scanners. Could be real or fake who cares. Its just annoying and feels like I am under some kind of snooping attack.

Comment: since the post of this complaint wifi service has been smooth...and I found a wifi monitoring utility..gonna keep it running and see what I catch.